How to deal with poorly worded assessment questions?
Question
I have taken several critical reasoning tests (CRTs) lately while applying for jobs at medium-to-large companies. On more than one occasion, I know or suspect that my application has been rejected based partly or wholly on a low CRT score. In my opinion, these CRTs are often poorly designed.
Is there a solution to this? I imagine companies will be reluctant to change their assessment procedures, which are often outsourced anyway, and since I'm an interested party it may be hard to convince them that I'm not simply looking for special consideration.

Example
Instructions

Each of the following questions consists of a statement followed by four suggested conclusions. Please consider the content of each statement to be completely true.
For each conclusion, you must indicate whether or not you think it follows from the statement.
If you think it follows from the statement, select 'Conclusion follows'. A conclusion follows if it is fully substantiated by the statement.
If you think it does not necessarily follow from the statement, select 'Conclusion does not follow'. A conclusion does not follow if it cannot be fully substantiated by the statement as it stands.
Do not supplement any statement with your own general knowledge and try not to let your attitude or opinions influence your decision as to whether each conclusion follows.
In any of the following statements, the word 'some' refers to an undetermined quantity of the category of 'things' under discussion. Therefore 'some' ranges from at least one to all. For example, 'some employees work full-time' means that the number working full-time is somewhere between one employee and all employees.

Statement

"Choosing a new company strategy is not always straightforward. There are some people who prefer diversification, while there are others who prefer specialisation. In the end, deciding on the strategy that is right for your company will be a compromise."

Conclusions


Choosing a company strategy is more complicated than people think.
It is impossible to get everything you want when choosing a strategy.
Choosing a company strategy involves a decision.
There are no people who like diversification and specialisation equally.


Analysis
I think (1) is simple. (1) does not follow, as people may have an accurate understanding that "Choosing a company is not always straightforward." and of the level of complication involved.
(2) leaves me asking, "Who is 'you'?". I would think that someone could want diversification and get it, in which case the conclusion does not follow. But we are told that "deciding on the strategy that is right for your company will be a compromise.", which sounds like not getting everything 'you' want, in which case the conclusion does follow.
(3) is confusing both in itself and in its implications for (2). Is there a difference between a choice and a decision? Not in common usage as I'm familiar with it. An internet search (which should be unnecessary according to the instructions) produced contradictory results with varying levels of justification. If there is no difference then choosing a company strategy is the same as deciding on a company strategy, so does involve a decision, - but this follows by definition, not from the statement. If there is a difference, then (3) should be answered 'Does not follow', since the statement tells us nothing about a connection between choosing a strategy and making a decision; and (2) should be answered 'Does not follow', since only 'deciding' is said to involve compromise, not 'choosing'.
(4) might appear not to follow as we are not told that the "some people who prefer diversification" and the "others who prefer specialisation" exhaust the range of person-preference pairings. But again, we are told that "deciding on the strategy that is right for your company will be a compromise."; would the 'compromise' be avoided by someone with equal preference? If so, then the conclusion does follow.
Comment
If this seems confusing - well, that's my point. If you think I'm needlessly overcomplicating it, perhaps you can explain why there is actually a single, clearly correct answer. Based on the number of questions and the suggested duration of the whole test, this question is expected to take about a minute!

Is it just a rant or is there a question there thats suitable for here?

Have you ever thought the use of these "critical reasoning tests" might be to weed out those who critically reason about the quality of the test?

@Steve Don't think that's occurred to me. I'm assuming it's at least partly in good faith.

@mjc, it depends what you mean by "good faith". The purpose of the test is at least ostensibly selection - selection for the company's profitability interests, not rewarding candidates for their perceived intellectual prowess or furthering the interests of political and economic fairness. They don't even see their self-preference as bad faith. Also you assume that these tests are written by profoundly intelligent people, so as to identify other profoundly intelligent people. Often they're actually written by monkeys to make money for a company that retails batteries of tests to employers.

@Steve Points taken; I just wish I knew how to pass, if not by application of critical reasoning.

Is there a typo / word ommision in your example? As it stands there is no connection between "Choosing a new company is not always straightforward" and the other sentences who seem to talk about choosing a new "company strategy". It doesn'T seem to be part of your criticism either...

@FrankHopkins Yes, thanks. I've edited the OP to fix.

bonus question for further answers: do you struggle with the time in such questionnaires or is it more that you feel you might incorrectly be sorted out because you answer everything but feel unsure in whether your answers were correct in the eyes of the interviewers?

@FrankHopkins The example question I gave is from an untimed online assessment, though the introduction says that answering 33 questions normally takes about 25 minutes, so it's expected to take less than 1 minute. I stared at this one question for maybe 30 minutes before formulating this stackexchange question, and I don't think there is a correct answer without further clarification. Adding time limits to poorly worded questions of course doesn't make them any easier.

As an English speaker those statements are perfectly written English.  In the context of the assignment “you” is the individual choosing the strategy. You might argue, but that’s circular logic, and it is and that’s the problem with the statement.  However, that doesn’t mean it’s not unclear or poorly worded statement. As someone else said “you” and “we” can be used to refer to the collective “we” and the generalized “you”. Might not be common outside of specific areas in the country though.

Is every example you answer like this one, or is this just a particularly bad example? If I search for the text from your example I find this https://www.assessmentday.co.uk/free/watson-glaser/freetest1/Deductions/Free-Critical-Thinking-Test-Deductions-Solutions.pdf. Your specific question is missing but the pre-amble is identical , so I expect this company wrote the test. The examples they give make more sense (to me) so I wonder are you getting hung up on a few bad examples, and spending too long at them, at the expense of the others

@Donald "Did you go left or right?" is also perfectly written English; it's just not clear what I'm referring to. After further thought about the strong suggestion embedded in (3) that choosing and deciding are significantly different, I've adjusted my understanding of those words, and would now say that the answer to (2) is fairly clearly "Does not follow", since only 'deciding' is said to necessitate compromise for 'you', not 'choosing'. I think it's unreasonable to expect someone to reach that conclusion in the approx. 40 seconds suggested time.

@mattfreake Thanks for the link. I found this example particularly difficult, but I've come across enough questions that I have the same sort of problem with to see it as something that's costly to just ignore. The test I encountered this question in was untimed, with no option to return to previously answered questions, so getting hung up on this one was a strategy with potential upside if it could be figured out.


Indeed, those questions from the example aren't perfect. However, personally, I'd find the questions quite a bit less confusing as you seem to do - though there is still some level of argument, as we can see from the different answers for them here. However, it doesn't necessarily matter much if there is some (reasonable) level of ambiguity, as:

Those tests are typically done in either of two contexts:



Weed out the really bad batch via statistics
Have a basis for an in-depth discussion about logical thinking

Statistical weed out
While not every question might be perfect, if you give people a hundred of them a pattern of who gets them mostly "right", i.e. in line with expected answers, should emerge. If the tests are at least half decent, a few questions that are confusing and thus result in some random noise don't matter much as long as a majority is formulated well enough for people with a healthy level of logical thinking can answer them correctly. This also helps you typically after a while to understand how the questions work and if they are meant more for you to check for literal meaning on a very low level or bring in at least some level of abstraction and interpretation. This is typically a rough brush when you have lots of applicants and want an easy way of filtering out a good bunch. It will have false positives but typically filter out a high percentage of hopeless candidates.
Basis for in-depth discussion
Especially those questions where people deviate from what the interviewer expected make for a great basis of an in-depth interview round. The interviewer might bring it such a question up to discuss the thought process of the interviewee. The interesting part often isn't whether someone gets to the right result, but how.
Why - because those questions need to be simple, condensed example and real world issues the employee will face will have more depth and complexity; the interviewee might simply have learned all such question collections by heart or used a hidden attribute of the test, like the 'right' answers following a pattern; the interviewer needs to decide how well the person fits into existing teams or how well their thought process would augment it etc.
Obviously in a good setup both can be combined: First weed out a good portion, then use the original questions as a basis for a deeper discussion.
Test size
Note that many tests are not meant to be fully completed. Often there are far more questions than any person can reasonably answer in the given time. Ideally whether you loose points if you don't complete all questions is made clear to you upfront. You can also always ask. Depending on that adjust your strategy a bit.
So as in how to deal with them:
As good as you can without spending too much time on a single question. Try to answer them as you initially feel and if you have time left you can go over those that seemed the least clear. Depending on the system your test is using (whether you can remove/adjust answers) you might also keep those to answer them at the end. Mostly you need to get a feeling how much time you can spend per question. If the test is so large you cannot complete it anyway, you can either skip questions that are too confusing or just answer them with your best guess. Try to establish a consistent approach (typically at the beginning the level at which the questions aim is a bit unclear but this should settle in the more questions you worked at). E.g, If all questions so far were meant very literal and you could perfectly answer them, it is unlikely one will suddenly completely violate that pattern and assume you think way more abstractly. The same holds the other way around.
As for an example interpretation of the question, for me

is false as not supported by the statements, there is no statement that says anything about what people think how complicated choosing a strategy is, that would involve outside assumptions.
is the one I would feel the most uncertain, but would say it is false as it makes a universal claim (impossible) and nothing in the statements excludes that someone might be happy with a simple choice, say on one of the two extreme ends mentioned that are mentioned. The only part that makes that a bit unclear is the line that says "deciding ... will be a compromise". So that could be argued both ways imho without outside assumptions.
this is clearly true as the statements clearly imply there is a scale between at least two extremes to pick from, it is not an automatic choice where you have only one automatic option
false, as no statement limits the preferences of people, among all of them one might be right in the middle

The main point however, imho, is not to get everything perfectly right, but good enough. Picking an interpretation of the rules that seems reasonable enough, allowing you to answer those questions without a philosophical essay (figuratively) in a reasonable amount of time. Only reevaluate that if you run into multiple questions where the interpretation seems not to work. (Also likely there are somewhere resources where one could get similar questions with answers that one could try out as a training exercise...). My interpretation might be wrong, but the point is, I don't need long to answer these questions and I would re-evaluate only when seeing other interpretations that are convincing and/or failing tests that seem like I should have passed.

My example question is copied verbatim from a real example. If you don't find this question confusing, could you say what you think the answers are and why? I would be much happier if these questions were used as a basis for in-depth discussion since, as you see, I have some relatively in-depth thoughts about them. Unfortunately I don't think I've come across any single example where that is the purpose. I think every case I've encountered is 'statistical weed-out', and unfortunately questions as ambiguous as this one are common enough to make passing tests difficult for me.

@Servaes Sure. I've got some try left in me before I accept that.

could also just mean you need to train yourself...

Perhaps. I have some training in English language, philosophy, and mathematical and computational logic, which forms part of my basis for thinking this is a poorly worded question. Maybe practising more assessments will help.

I think your problem is that you are over-thinking this and taking it over-literally. At least about this question, you are treating it like a logic problem, whereas in fact it's about understanding the way people normally write and communicate.
For example, your analysis of question 4 is far too complicated. In normal speech, when people say "some people prefer X, some people prefer Y" that is a generalisation indicating a range of opinion. It doesn't preclude people who like both X and Y. The rest of what you write about compromise is irrelevant.
In question 2 "you" is the general "you", meaning "people in general". The statement is right there that "deciding on the strategy that is right for your company will be a compromise" meaning that the general person will not get everything they want. Remember you don't have to agree with a conclusion to say it follows from the statements.
Statements 1 and 3 do involve some thought, and are not definitely not logically exact. But this does reflect real life. For my money 1 is true (because why would you write these statements if everybody knew strategies were complicated) and 3 is true (because the statements talk about a decision). Choice and decision are not always synonymous, as seen in the phrase "I choose not to make a decision".
It is possible that questions like this are actually designed to weed out people who treat everything like a logic puzzle. Such people are not always suited for all kinds of jobs, and in some cases can be difficult to work with, especially if they don't realise that other people don't think like that.

So the tests may be designed to favour people who don't read the question carefully, who don't think things through logically, who make assumptions and overgeneralisations and are generally lax in their thinking???

@DJClayworth I think different thinking styles can be complementary. I think any company that touches on STEM, including computer science, will have to have some sort of interest in, or at least tolerance for, people who tend to treat things as puzzles. It may be a disadvantage to me that years of training have dulled my sense of normal, fuzzy interpretation; but I don't think I could ever have written a computer script or solved a maths problem if I didn't question the meaning behind words and symbols. If they really do want to filter me out, I'll live with that.

Also, "the way people normally write and communicate" is often full of ambiguities that can lead to costly, avoidable mistakes. The relevance of compromise to (4) is that someone who is indifferent to specialisation vs diversification might choose a strategy without needing to compromise, which we are told does not happen. For (2), perhaps the main sticking point for me now is that we are told about "deciding on the strategy", then asked about "Choosing a company strategy", and 'choosing' and 'deciding' may be unrelated, given their clear separation in (3).

@gidds No. The question might be designed to weed out people who think that strict logic and exact definitions of words are the only way to approach questions, and ignore common understandings. The ideal person would be able to think logically,  read carefully, etc. but also know that not everybody works like that and be able to deal with the ambiguity present in normal human communication.

@mjc Yes, it's very position dependent. The inability to handle the ambiguity of normal communication are not a big problem in a strictly programming role for example, but might be in any k8nd of leadership role. And some companies don't want to hire developers who could never be leaders.

@DJClayworth I think you may be overstating the extent to which I understand normal communication less that others, though. I think 'normal' people incorrectly interpret each other's ambiguity plenty often. I would even say that role-modelling the importance of precise communication can be a valuable leadership quality. I think these test questions really are poorly worded.

Possibly. I can only go by what you write here. And I wouldn't disagree that statements 1 and 3 are not entirely clear. But I think 2 and 4 are pretty clear in normal usage.

@mjc: "I think any company that touches on STEM, including computer science, will have to have some sort of interest in, or at least tolerance for, people who tend to treat things as puzzles." The issue with your response to this question is that you're treating it like it is only a logic puzzle and are glossing over the everyday communication inferences that a workplace generally operates on, which is especially important when hiring a technical person who has to interact with non-technical staff. I believe that that is what the test is weeding out, and I think this answer does too.

@mjc ""the way people normally write and communicate" is often full of ambiguities that can lead to costly, avoidable mistakes" Your take on this is a significant red flag to me for a hiring process. This again strikes on the same "logic and nothing but logic" attitude that blames any semantics that are not based on formal logic, instead of displaying an ability to work with it. It's not just about how well you apply your formal logic and technical skill, it's about how well you are able to work with the people who you will be working with without blaming their communication style.

@mjc "I would even say that role-modelling the importance of precise communication can be a valuable leadership quality." This is turning away from a bad interview question, straight into you outright disagreeing with what the company values in an employee. That is not your call to make. You disagree with the company, and you instead resort to blaming the question quality and everyday communication patterns, while still repeating how right your take on things is and how the way you understand things is the better way to lead. It highlights undesirable work-cultural qualities in an employee.

@Flater Thanks for the thoughtful comments. I understand what's normally thought of as 'logic' isn't always the key to understanding what someone's trying to say. I think framing something as a 'critical reasoning test', and giving instructions about 'evidence', 'assumptions', 'drawing conclusions', etc., invites a focus on those things. I don't 'blame' people's communication style in the sense of telling them it's wrong, but I frequently ask clarifying questions, motivated by a perception of multiple valid interpretations.

@Flater If I see a work culture that makes costly, avoidable mistakes through ambiguous communication, then yes, I disagree that that's an optimal culture. Sure, it's not my call to make about whether they continue like that. It is my call as to whether I allow a desire to be employed to blind me to such things, and I'm trying not to go too far in that direction. I think if no one ever points out problems because everyone's going along to get along, things don't get fixed.

@Flater I think saying I'm disagreeing with the company rather than the test assumes they really do want to use the test to select for the right kind of ambiguity-reading (distinguishing between choice and decision is not an every-day pattern, in my experience, or according to the internet reading I did to try to figure out what they were getting at). That assumption could be right, or it could be an unintended effect of out-sourcing assessments. I've heard a mid-level management acquaintance complain about the latter.

Seems fairly straightforward to me. The question is not poorly worded; they are testing reading comprehension and ability to draw reasonable conclusions from what was written.
2 is unsupported by the statement, which says only that there may be conflicting goals. It does not say that reconciling them is IMPOSSIBLE; it says that it is NOT ALWAYS EASY. Big difference.
4 is unsupported by the statement. There is no statement or implication that rules out folks who give both equal weighting. "Others" is not "all others."
Remainder left as an exercise for the reader, now that I've illustrated how they expect you to approach these. Essentially, answer strictly on the facts given. This is testing only reading comprehension and logic; if they wanted a list of additional questions that should be considered before answering, they would have made it an essay question.

Expanding upon my initial answer...
Key points from the Instructions
Please consider the content of each statement to be completely true.
For each conclusion, you must indicate whether or not you think it follows from the statement.
A conclusion follows if it is fully substantiated by the statement. A conclusion does not follow if it cannot be fully substantiated by the statement as it stands.
Do not supplement any statement with your own general knowledge and try not to let your attitude or opinions influence your decision as to whether each conclusion follows.
'some' ranges from at least one to all.
In other words: answer based only, and exactly, on the statement as it has been made. Anything which was not explicitly stated is not to be considered. You are being graded on how well you can understand and carry out these instructions, in addition to how well you understand the statement and questions.

Statement

Choosing a new company strategy is not always straightforward. There
are some people who prefer diversification, while there are others who
prefer specialisation. In the end, deciding on the strategy that is
right for your company will be a compromise.

Conclusions
1. Choosing a company strategy is more complicated than people think.
I would say unsupported. I think it's clear that the statement's author intended to illustrate the complexity of this task, presumably for readers who weren't aware of these issues, and on casual reading I would draw this conclusion. But the statement does not say this explicitly, and the instructions emphasize taking the statement in isolation from any other knowledge or expectations. Given that, I think I have to override my instinctive reading of the intent and answer not fully supported. And if the grader claimed it was supported, I would present this rationale and ask them to justify their answer given the rules they wrote.
Having said that, this is the one question that is, in fact, less than clear; with other instructions, or on pure test taking skills, I would have been inclined to answer it the other way. But we have our marching orders, and we need to follow them.
2. It is impossible to get everything you want when choosing a strategy.
Unsupported. Impossible is an overly strong conclusion. While the statement says there can be disagreements and reconciling them is "not always easy", it does not say there must be disagreements, and in fact "not always" implies that sometimes finding the balance is easy. Your group may be in full agreement on how to balance potentially conflicting goals.
Weaker argument: In English, the second person pronoun "you" may be either singular or collective. A negotiated compromise might be an exact match for your own individual preferences, in which case you (singular) do get everything you want even if that isn't true for everyone.
Generally, beware of conclusions expressed as absolutes. They aren't automatically false, but they are automatically suspect. For me, the answer to this one jumped out.
3. Choosing a company strategy involves a decision.
Supported. The statement applies both of these words directly to this task (in this order!).
Weaker argument: Choice and decision are synonyms.

There are no people who like diversification and specialisation equally.

Unsupported. The statement says "some" favor one side of the balance while "others" (not "all the others"!) may favor the other end of the spectrum. In this situation, "others", like "some", can take values ranging from one to everybody. (I would say from it nobody to everybody, but we are explicitly told that some implies at least one.) If the sum (some plus others) is less than the total number of individuals, those not included in these two groups, by definition, have no preference. And there is nothing in the statement which forbids that stance.

The answer is appreciated, but I have trouble agreeing that your interpretations are the only, or even mostly obviously, valid ones. The statement says "deciding on the strategy that is right for your company WILL be a compromise.", which I think could easily be interpreted to mean that (2) follows as written. Similarly, that "deciding on the strategy that is right for your company WILL be a compromise" can easily be interpreted to mean that NO ONE can be indifferent to such a decision, since a compromise would not be necessary for such a person; hence (4) would follow.

You're overthinking this. Admittedly I grew up with reading comprehension questions in this form. Take the statements at their most literal.

Assume that the questions are not poorly worded , but that every word was carefully chosen.

If every word was carefully chosen I think the problem was designed either by someone with a very different idea of logic to me or for reasons other than testing critical thinking.

I strongly suspect it isn't primarily a critical thinking test. It is a reading comprehension test, plis ability to draw direct inferences. If they really wanted you to go beyond that, they would be asking you to explain your rationale.

Don't try to draw extended conclusions. Answer only on the basis of the statement they are quizzing you about

Unlike the higher rated, and accepted, answers, I think this one actually gets to the problem. If you carefully follow the directions in the prompt there is only one single obvious answer. I do think this answer could be improved by being more explicit about how there’s only one logical choice; not because it’s required to explain the fundamental question, but rather to convince others that this answer is correct. Character limits in comments don’t leave me enough room to do this myself, else I would.

Rereading this, note that the instructions explicitly say that you should answer only on the basis of what has been explicitly stated, not based on opinions or experience outside the scope of the test. Don't interpolate. Don't try to read it for questions behind the questions. Don't ask for additional data; you have been told not to use it. Don't guess at conditions not explicitly stated. Don't let your own preferences affect your answers. If you think more than one answer is defensible, pick the one that is most strongly supported/truest.

Note that part of what this is testing is your ability to read, understand, and follow the instructions.

@mkdir: Detailed arguments have now been added. In the process, I decided  that I really do not like the way they have written conclusion (1). Then again, I also don't like the fact that they say "some will" rather than "some may"; by their rules the former is at least one while the latter would permit zero. So, yes, the writing could be better... But it's clear enough to illustrate the principles upon which I would solve this assignment, and how I would defend my answers if challenged.

Analyzing the given example: Only item #3 necessarily follows from the given statements.

Counterexample to #1: Possibly everyone knows that "Choosing a new company strategy is not always straightforward", that is, are aware of the complexity.

Counterexample to #2: Possibly Alice prefers diversification, and Bob prefers specialization. They compromise by splitting the company in two, each following their ideal strategy.

Counterexample to #4: Possibly Alice prefers diversification, Bob prefers specialization, and Carol likes each equally. This satisfies all the criteria.


Conclusion #3 follows simply because the statement refers to "deciding on the strategy", i.e., there's a decision being made.

EDIT based on OP's comment below.
Communication and perception. Look at it from the hiring company's point of view. There is a sets of criteria that they want. Specific criteria of skill and general skills. Rather than bending what you are reading to your point of view, try your hardest to answer as what they want.
Your OP reads like a rant. If that wasn't your intent, then you didn't look at your own writing. This isn't a ding, it is a teaching moment. Why did several of us read the OP as a rant?
When asking for help or making a plan, the basics are to access where you are, where you want to be, and what are the viable paths. A rant is "I am here and everyone else should be here too" or something similar. Which of these does your OP read like?
Your OP reads as if you don't really have a problem giving the answers that you think that they expect. It just seems that you don't like their tests. If I am wrong, I appologize. If you are truly asking for actionable help to improve your test results, I am missing it.
From my experience people that rant like you did think the world should bend to your thinking.
Life doesn't work that way. The hiring company has their criteria and it's their right. Play their game or move on.
No company want to hire a pain in the A**. They are focused on getting accomplished what they want to get accomplished. They aren't going to hire people that won't test they way they think will foretell sucess. Nor will they hire people just be told how bad they are.
If they want to hire people that think a specific way, that is their choice. Your choice is if you know what they want, do you want to give it when testing to get the job.
Is this harsh? Maybe. But it is true and meant to point out that the choice is yours. You aren't going to change them.
Is it better to be right or to be employed?

Apology accepted. I am truly asking for actionable help. You're the third person to describe my post as a 'rant', for reasons which I don't really understand. I do have a problem giving the answers I think that they expect, because I can't figure out what answers they expect. I do have ideas about how I think the world should be, but try not to be pushy about it; and if I didn't have any such ideas, I don't know what value I would be providing. I'd like to strike a balance between being right and being employed, since I want to keep my soul.

Whilst this reads as a Rant, I think there is a question that one can answer here:
You answer in the way that you think your prospective employer would want you to answer
What do I mean by this?
Well, I am not going to analyze the snippet you posted - but for example, I am aware that certain companies have DIE goals.
I am philosophically opposed to this.
So, when I am filling out my forms or they ask a question about DIE - do I answer that the whole concept has its genesis in Antonio Gramscii trying to work out why a Communist revolution never happened in the UK - and the conclusion was that it was because of high levels of trust in their social institutions and therefore the only way to achieve a revolution was to undermine those social institutions?
No, I right some vague twaddle about overcoming systemic problems and equity and blah blah blah because I know that is what the employer wants to hear
In short:
Even if you think the Test is the biggest load of BS, you answer it from the perspective what your employer wants to hear
For your specific example, assume the test is well-worded, answer it on that basis. See how far you get.

Most of my point is that there isn't a single, well-worded interpretation.

This answer doesn't seem to apply in the example given

@mjc - then you pick the closest to what you think the company wants to hear, rather than nitpicking a test you think is wrong.

The questions OP mentions don't seem to be politically loaded or opinion based. So, while the general idea of "answering how you think they should be answered" is certainly valid OP's struggle seems to be that they don't know what the expected answer is. That's a bit like saying just solve the (potentially ill formulated) math equation like you think the company wants it to be solved, when OP's problem is that they don't get the question statement as to them it is not clear (from their point of view because the equation is ambiguously denoted).

So you might want to expand on how that translates to this particular style of questions...

What is ‘DIE’?  Is it an acronym?

@gidds I assume it's a rearrangement of DEI, 'Diversity, Equity and Inclusion'. Since TheDemonLord is philosophically opposed to this, I'm guessing he considers 'DIE' a more descriptive abbreviation.
